# How to split a table in R into two parts

Tags: r

I have a table loaded in R with a number of variables. One of the variables is Binomial (it says 1 or 0). I would like to split my table into two parts, one containing all the rows where this variable prints "1" and the other containing the remaining rows. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use the subset() function.

IF X is your data.frame with a variable var1

```
X1 <- subset(X, var1=="0")
X2 <- subset(X, var1=="1")
```

Comment: thank you, it worked. Just wondering why the negatives by my question but never mind.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use a `split` and then create a `list` of two data.frames

```
lst1 <- split(X, var1)
```